# for loop comparison over enhanced for loop in concurrent modification exception

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I was reading about concurrent modification exception and noticed in case of element removal using enhanced for loop throws concurrent modification exception whereas normal for loop doesn't.
Can someone please help me understand why this is happening, below code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ConcurrentModificationExceptionExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

        myList.add("1");
        myList.add("2");
        myList.add("3");
        myList.add("4");
        myList.add("5");

        // enhanced for loop
/*     for(String s:myList){
         if(s.equals("1")){
             myList.remove("1");
         }
     }*/
// normal for loop
        for(int i = 0; i<myList.size(); i++){
            if(myList.get(i).equals("1")){
                myList.remove("1");
            }
        }

        System.out.println(myList);


    }
}
```

for testing //enhanced for loop can be uncommented

Comment: I'm curious, does the normal for loop actually work correctly if you insert several consecutive 1's in there? The logic should be faulty, with the second consecutive 1 not being seen since `i` is incremented even when the remove happens.

Answer (score 2):

This is because in your "normal for loop" code no `Iterator` is involved. Instead, you access the elements individually with `get`.

Answer (score 2):

The loop notation

```
for (String s: myList) {
    ...
}
```

creates an iterator object behind the scenes. The iterator keeps track of collection modifications. When you make a modification without using the iterator you will get a ConcurrentModificationException.

When using

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    ...
}
```

and accessing the collection with

```
myList.get(i)
```

there is no iterator created, and therefore no chance for the exception to be thrown.